# Calculating an AMT Finance in C#

Tags: c#

Trying to make a program that calculates Tax on a total amount. It was working but I realized I need to output the value to a decimal for later use. I'm making a car payment calculator so I need all this data for later use. This code outputs nothing.

```
private void buttonPayment_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        decimal sellPrice = 0;
        decimal stateTax = 0;

        sellPrice = Convert.ToDecimal(textBoxSellPrice.Text);
        sellPrice = Decimal.Parse(textBoxSellPrice.Text);


        if (comboBoxState.Text.Contains("NJ"))
        { 
            stateTax = .0685M;
        }

        if (comboBoxState.Text.Contains("DE"))
        {
            stateTax = .0425M;
        }

        if (comboBoxState.Text.Contains("PA"))
        {
            stateTax = .06M;
        }


        labelTax.Text = Decimal.Multiply(sellPrice, stateTax).ToString();
    }
```

Comment: you are assigning to salePrice twice.

Comment: thanks for the reply. Still outputs nothing though.... Like this was working a little bit ago but I tried storing the amount of tax to a decimal and I couldnt get it to do anything after this point and even trying to go backwards is screwing me up and outputting nothing

Comment: whats the value of comboBoxState.Text? eg: put a break point (F8) inside `buttonPayment_Click` and check whats going

Answer (score 0):

I did manage to solve this! I accidentally deleted the call to action for the click of the button. So nothing ever actually happened when I clicked the button cause I accidentally deleted it in past debugging.

Thanks for the advice though!

Comment: You would have figured this out if you created an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) in the first place. Waste a lot less of other people's time that way.